# Efficiently replace all substring appearances in pure Bash

Tags: bash

I want to replace **all** substrings from a string using pure Bash (without awk, perl or sed).

This line:

```
string=${string/$oldValue/$newValue}
```

replaces only the first `$oldValue` appearance.

This is why I did it in the following way:

```
while [[ $string == *"$oldValue"* ]]; do
    string=${string/$oldValue/$newValue}
done
```

but I don't like this "ugly" (=inefficient) approach.

Is there a better way to do this? (probably a generalized form for the first line of code)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try something like:

```
export str="Hello World Hello"
export oldValue="Hello"
export newValue="Hi"
echo ${str//$oldValue/$newValue}
Hi World Hi
```

Answer (score 3):

Add an extra `/` to replace all `$oldValue` by `$newValue`:

```
string="${string//$oldValue/$newValue}"
```